# Drupal site offline due to MySQL connection

Tags: drupal

I have just moved my site from developpement plateform to production.
I configure the setting files in the $db_url string. I have put the good ones because I use these credential in a shell to access th database, there is no problem.
But when I try to access my site I get the following message:

> Site off-line
>   The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.
>
> If you are the maintainer of this site, please check your database settings in the settings.php file and ensure that your hosting provider's database server is running. For more help, see the handbook, or contact your hosting provider.

Comment: it was due to special character with are not allowed in $dburl string: %20 for + ....

Comment: please post the solution as an answer and accept it when you can

Answer (score 2):

you will see this message if drupal can't connect to its database....check the filed settings.php again...and make sure that the database, username and password are correct and no problem with connecting to the database